# is possible to create a boolean matrix with flutter?

Tags: flutter, matrix

I'm trying flutter for the first time and I'm trying to create a boolean matrix. Is possibile to use it with flutter?
I'm searching something like this(with flutter):

```
boolean[index_row][index_columns] = new boolean[][];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var nCols = 10;
  var nRows = 12;
  var boolMatrix1 = List<List<bool>>();
  var boolMatrix2 = List<List<bool>>.generate(nRows, (i) => List<bool>.generate(nCols, (j) => true));
```